# Why Can't Some Commercial Bonds Be Bought Through Major Brokers?

Tags: bonds, brokerage, broker, fixed-income

I am interested in buying a commercial bond issued by a coal mining company.  The CUSIP is `62704PAM5`.  I searched online at tdameritrade.com and was not able to find the bond using their bond search tool.  I called in to the fixed income department at TD Ameritrade and they were not able to find it either.

Is there a reason a commercial bond like the one I referenced above wouldn't be available through a major broker?  The issuer, Murray Energy, is a top 5 coal producer in the United States and is rated by the major credit agencies.

Comment: "I searched online at tdameritrade.com and was not able to find the bond". I see it at Vanguard and Fidelity.  "Is there a reason a commercial bond like the one I referenced above wouldn't be available through a major broker?"  Maybe TDA has decided not to trade in coal company bonds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Murray Energy is privately held, so there is apparently not much of a secondary market for their bonds.

If you are interesting in purchasing their bonds, the [investor page](http://murrayenergycorp.com/investors/) of their website provides a phone number and email address you can use to contact them directly.